# How to make my code more secure and one more

Tags: python, security, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm working at some project, where i need strong security, because it works with networks.
So, I've made a class for token storage, which encrypts this token via pycrypto, encodes it in base64, and reverse.

Steps are following:

> - Set up AES encryption keys
> - Initialize token object
> - Encrypt it

I need to make sure that there's not any holes in security, and also I'm interested in knowledge: **How to make any class/method/variable accessible in only one file?**

**Code**:

```py
from base64  import b64encode, b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
 
import sys
import math
 
class Token:
 
    print("[cobalt] setting up encrytion keys...")
    print("[cobalt] reading encryption key file")
 
    key = open('/usr/share/doc/cobalt/encryption', 'r')
    lines = key.readlines()[0].split(':')
 
    print("[cobalt] read values, writing private constants...")
    __COMMON_ENCRYPTION_KEY = lines[0].strip()
    __COMMON_AES_IV16 = lines[1].strip()
 
    del lines
    key.close()
 
    print("[cobalt] wrote constants, closing file stream...")
    print("[cobalt] setted up encryption keys, initializing token object...")
 
    def __init__(self, token:str):
        self._token = token
        self._encrypted = self.__encrypt()
 
        print("[cobalt] token object initialized")
 
    def __get_common(self):
        print("[cobalt] getting common AES...")
        try:
            return AES.new(Token.__COMMON_ENCRYPTION_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, Token.__COMMON_AES_IV16)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"[cobalt]\033[1;31m error:\033[m {e}")
            sys.exit(1)
 
    def __encrypt(self) -> str:
        print("[cobalt] encrypting token...")
 
        common_cipher = self.__get_common(); print(f"[cobalt] got common AES: {common_cipher}")
        token_len = len(self._token); print(f"[cobalt] got token length: {token_len}")
 
        # padded token with next multiple of 16
        padded_token = self._token.rjust(16 * math.ceil(token_len / 16)); print("[cobalt] got padded token")
        raw_encrypted_token = common_cipher.encrypt(padded_token); print("[cobalt] encrypted, encoding...\n")
 
        return b64encode(raw_encrypted_token).decode('utf-8')
 
    def _decrypt(self) -> str:
        print("[cobalt] decrypting token...")
 
        common_cipher = self.__get_common(); print(f"[cobalt] got common AES: {common_cipher}")
        raw_token = b64decode(self._encrypted); print("[cobalt] decoded raw token")
        decrypted_wpadding = common_cipher.decrypt(raw_token); print("[cobalt] decrypted token\n")
 
        return decrypted_wpadding.decode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: short answer for _How to make any class/method/variable accessible in only one file_ is define everything inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement

Comment: Do you know that there is also [codereview.se]?

Comment: I'd split I/O and use a logging lib. By the way, the python base 64 encoder doesn't provide any streaming and not even conversion to string; these devs must love spending memory like there is no tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storage you should use one-way functions (sha-2, for example), because you will never need to have its actual value, so you will never need to decode it. Each time user try to get access and use his token (password, cvv code or etc), you just use the same function upon the token and waiting to get the exact same result.

For accessibility you can use `accessify`

```
from accessify import private, protected


class Unit:

    @protected
    def move(self):
        pass

    @private
    def run(self):
        pass
```

**Personal thoughts you probably should ignore:**

Also I noticed, you use "__". It's good practise, when you want to ship your library to the world. Competent user will not use this methods (and IDE will not provide information about them :)). But it won't save your from bad-bad people. So I personally don't see the point of usage this ugly notation here, when you're coding your server application.